# Ribbon not showing up on My Sites?

Tags: my-site, ribbon, my-profile

I'm having a weird issue with the top ribbon on MySites. This has been like this from the beginning even before I have added some CSS, so I don't think that would be the problem.

[image]

Basically, what is happening is that the ribbon expands but none of the options are visible. However, if I click on 'Add Web Part' all options will become visible on the ribbon. This is also only happening on the My Profile page, if I go to edit my settings the ribbon works fine.

Any idea why this is happening? The image shows the ribbon without any options in it, but as I mentioned they appear when you select 'Add Web Part' on the page.

Thank you!

Comment: Any ideas for how to fix this? I still haven't found a solution...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check your masterpage for the following line.

```
<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
```

and remove the s4-ribbonrowhidetitle class...

```
<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr">
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it, when I remove the s4-ribbonrowhidetitle and apply my CSS there is nothing in that ribbon area, I can see the background of the page but no options show up at all. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's all it had taken me. I was in the same circumstance on my mysite page. Did you try this on both the custom and primary pages? or are they both the same for you?

Comment: Well I have a custom master page and I tried it there but it did not work, so then I deactivated my custom masterpage and tried on the regular mysite.master and minimal.master and still nothing. This all works fine on my test environment but not on production and its the exact same files, so I'm not too sure what could be going on

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on SharePoint 2013's mysites.

The solution for me was to add my account to the User Profile Service Application's Administrators group in Central Admin.

After doing that, I had the ribbon in mysites.